# Plotting scatter density plots in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, density-plot

I have data in the form of a table whose individual rows are in the form `(x,y,Nxy)`. Here `(x,y)` corresponds to a 2-D point and `Nxy` is the number of times this point has occurred. I want to draw a scatter-density plot such that color at a point gives how dense it is. I looked at the existing answers but most of them have data in `(x,y)` format from which the density can be calculated.

Comment: if you provide some sample data we could help.

Comment: if you want to use `bokeh` you can also use the `color` argument as in this (more complex) [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/elements.html)